# Rails 3 jquery form wizard: how to change action to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I am using jquery's form wizard with rails 3. I can not get it to allow server side validation. I think what is causing this is the action on the form is "/users" when it should be "json.html". How do you change the action of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is RESTful, but if you really want to change this, take a look at the `:url` option of `form_for`:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for